# Unable to understand import via __using__ macro Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using Phoenix framework and trying to create a plug for authentication, but am stuck with an error. Below is this sample code.

```
defmodule ChhutiServer.GoogleAuthController do
  use ChhutiServer.Web, :controller
  use ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth
end

# inside lib/plugs

defmodule ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth do
  import Plug.Conn

  defmodule ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth do
    @callback callback(Plug.Conn.t, map) :: any
  end

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      plug ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth
    end
  end
end
```

Above code returns below error.

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/google_auth_controller.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.init/1 (module ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth is not available)
    ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.init([])
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:198: Plug.Builder.init_module_plug/3
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:186: anonymous fn/4 in Plug.Builder.compile/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1387: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:186: Plug.Builder.compile/3
    (phoenix) expanding macro: Phoenix.Controller.Pipeline.__before_compile__/1
    web/controllers/google_auth_controller.ex:1: ChhutiServer.GoogleAuthController (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8
```

I understand the error is due to elixir looking for `ChhutiServe.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhuttiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth` instead of `ChhuttiServe.Plugs.GoogleAuth`. And I am also able to solve this issue by prepending modules with Elixir namespace. ie by using below code.

```
defmodule ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth do
  import Plug.Conn

  defmodule ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth do
    @callback callback(Plug.Conn.t, map) :: any
  end

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      plug Elixir.ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth
    end
  end
end
```

But I am not able to understand why its behaving like this. Can anyone please help me out.

**UPDATE**

Add all required code.

Comment: What are the contents of `MyApp.Web`? The code above should run without problems.

Comment: MyApp.Web is the default module generated by phoenix(web.ex file). It Does not contain any line added by me. Should I post entire code here. Files have many lines of code so i avoided pasting it here. But I think i missed to paste buggy parts. I will post a link of github repo here instead of pasting everything here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue was because I have declared module `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` inside `ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth`. But error reported is very strange and misleading. Moving `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` outside `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` solves the issue. One more strange thing that I noticed is moving `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` below the `__using__` macro also removes the error. As error report looks strange , I raised an issue. Below is the issue

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/4120

**Update**

Jose Valim helped me to understand that it is not an issue and its due to alias created when we defined nested module. I will explain why we get above error so that other people facing similar issue may understand the concept.

Whenever we create a nested module in elixir we are creating aliase for the nested module. Below is the example.

```
defmodule A do
  defmodule B do
  end
end
```

Above code is equivalent to

```
defmodule A.B do
end

defmodule A do
  alias A.B, as: B
end
```

So nested module creates the alias so that it can be accessed inside the parent module without  fully-qualified name i.e we can use `B` instead of `A.B` directly inside A to access B.

Now lets come to my question and check whats going on and understand the error generated.

```
defmodule ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth do
  import Plug.Conn


  defmodule ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth do
    @callback callback(Plug.Conn.t, map) :: any
  end


  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      plug ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth
    end
  end
end
```

In above code module `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` is nested within `ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth`. So fully-qualified name of `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` is `ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth`. As we have seen nested module creates the alias, above code is same as

```
  defmodule ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth do
    @callback callback(Plug.Conn.t, map) :: any
  end

  defmodule ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth do
    import Plug.Conn
    alias ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth, as: ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth   

    defmacro __using__(_) do
     quote do
       plug ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth
     end
    end
  end
```

Due to this alias now `ChhutiServer` points to `ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer` so that we can use `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` inside module
`ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth` instead of using full qualified name `ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth`. Then when we use
`plug ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth` inside  `__using__` macro it gets expanded to `plug ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth` as now
`ChhutiServer` points to `ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer`. And there comes our error as elixir is not able to find the module
`ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth.ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth`

Also I pointed out in question that when we define module `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` below `__using__` macro then the above code runs without any error.
This is because alias are lexically scoped in elixir. So if we bring `ChhutiServer.Behaviour.GoogleAuth` below `__using__` macro the alias is defined below the macro.
So `plug ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth` is not expanded to anything and it  remains as it is. And elixir is able to find `ChhutiServer.Plugs.GoogleAuth`. Small example to explain above thing.

defmodule A.B do
  def b do
  end
end

defmodule A do
  def a do
    # will return error "module B is not available" as A.B is not aliased yet.
    # If we want to call `b` we have to write it as `A.B.b`
    B.b
  end
  alias A.B, as: B
end

If we use alias before using `B` it will work.

defmodule A do
  alias A.B, as: B
  def a do
    B.b
  end
end

Hope this helps other to understand nested module and alias. Thanks Jose Valim for the explanation

References:

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/4120

Comment: Thank you for your report. I tried to solve your issue with no luck. But now, after your post and after @josevalim reply to your issue i've got better understanding  how aliases and nested modules work. You could also edit your post with explanation here from issue report.

Comment: @DmitryBiletskyy Sure i will update the post once i get clear on few points.  I am still somewhat unclear and have posted other questions on same issue. Will wait till i get completely clear.  Can you also check the question posted on the issue.  You might have the answer i am looking for.

Comment: @DmitryBiletskyy Added some details to the answer to explain the issue in detail